# Script to manage a file with large amounts of data

Tags: python

Hello I started to writing code in python and I have problem with simple script to make data readable to csv.

I have data like this in file.txt

```
{
"tv",
"64g3jf3",
"12.99", "OK",
"This is example text"

"Computer mouse",
"3tj82hg",
"15.99", "Canceled",
"Another, example text"
}
```

As you can see the data is scattered around, this file is 50MB so I have thousands of lines. I would like to convert this data on something like this and write to file.csv:

```
{

"tv","64g3jf3","12.99", "OK","This is example text"
"Computer mouse","3tj82hg","15.99", "Canceled","Another, example text"

}
```

I know how to make it in Bash but I need a python script ;/
I spent the whole day looking for a solution, but to no avail

This is original data:

```
"TV",
"250.00",
"SAMSUNG", "U2KXXH",
"15-APR-22", "BA6E7E4FFD",          "1699",          "250", "OK",
"83s5554c-5de76-4a",
"Media Markt POLAND Sp. z. o.o. Zielona Gora SK , UL. WROCLAWSKA)"
                                                                                
"TV",
"50NANO883PB",
"50NANO883PB",
"21-APR-22" "1D687576103",          "2899",           "250", "OK",
"19dwc527-0344-4029",
"Mediaexpert S338 (Bydgoszcz (city))"
                                                                                
"TV",
"8606091258922",
"32LQ570", "LG",
"27-APR-22", "8A71",           "949",           "250", "OK",
"57f5478-t4d0-4341-b144",
"Auchan Sosnowiec (Sosnowiec (city))"
```

Comment: So your script must read the file, replace ','+newline with ', '  then replace double newline with single newline, and write the result to a new file

Comment: @Stefan It's not that simple: `"Another, example text"` has a comma within the string that must not be replaced.

Comment: yeah, im trying make this using re, is that good tool for this?

Comment: Where does the data come from? Are the curly braces part of the input? If it's a standard format, chances are there is some library to parse the input into a Python structure that you can then format as you wish.

Comment: No, I make this {}

Comment: @FrescoBresco Can you please provide an example of the input data format without anything added to it? Otherwise it's hard to recognize the pattern. (You can edit your question.)

Comment: If your data is four lines in each record, you can read them and one you read four of them, then insert a new line in your csv. Each of your four data which are read, are considered as your fields of one record.

Comment: @fsimonjetz if you replace comma and newline in one go, it will work.

Comment: @Stefan You're right. I missed that you wrote ','+ newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the input data consists of blocks separated by an empty line.

```py
"tv",
"64g3jf3",
"12.99", "OK",
"This is example text"

"Computer mouse",
"3tj82hg",
"15.99", "Canceled",
"Another, example text"

"foo", "bar",
"foobar",
"baz", "foobaz"
```

In that case, you could get the individual blocks by splitting at empty lines (i.e., two newlines `\n\n`) and then replacing the single newlines in each block by a simple space:

```py
prettified = "\n".join(block.replace("\n", " ") for block in data.split("\n\n"))
```

Result:

```py
>>> print(prettified)
"tv", "64g3jf3", "12.99", "OK", "This is example text"
"Computer mouse", "3tj82hg", "15.99", "Canceled", "Another, example text"
"foo", "bar", "foobar", "baz", "foobaz"
```

Comment: And how you download data from file?